# PHP fails to send UTF-8 Messages

Tags: php, html, unicode

I have the following PHP code:

```
<?php

$to      = 'info@neatgr.cf';
$subject = date("d/m/Y");
$message = 'Hey 123 !@# αβγ';

$headers  = "From: testsite < mail@testsite.com >\n";
$headers .= "Cc: testsite < mail@testsite.com >\n"; 
$headers .= "X-Sender: testsite < mail@testsite.com >\n";
$headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
$headers .= "X-Priority: 1\n"; // Urgent message!
$headers .= "Return-Path: mail@testsite.com\n"; // Return path for errors
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Message sent! We will get back to you soon!');</script>";
echo "<script>window.location.href = 'http://example.com';</script>";
?>
```

The mail gets sent fine. The problem is that `αβγ` (Unicode Characters) doesn't get on the mail recipient's end correctly.

This is what the recipient sees: `Hey 123 !@# Î±Î²Î³`
This is what he should see: `Hey 123 !@# αβγ`

I've looked everywhere and tried everything, changing headers, converting my string to unicode etc. etc., but nothing has worked. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Possibly an issue with the actual reader?

Comment: you're using the wrong charset.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner How do I fix this?

Comment: You are saying the character encoding is IOS 8859, in your header, so the mail client will try to interpret your bytes at 8859-1

Comment: use the UTF-8 charset

Comment: I see someone just posted what was intended.

Comment: So that worked!

But this didn't...
```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$message = $postdata
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `UTF-8` charset header, for example:

```
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
```

Goes to:

```
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";
```